# Ringed buffer in C Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to assign a given amount of values from a ringed buffer to an array.

The buffer looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
     char* buffer;
     int8_t* buffer_end;
     int8_t* data_start;
     int8_t* data_end;
     int64_t count;
     int64_t size;
 } ring_buffer;
```

and I'm taking out data using this function

```
uint8_t RB_pop(ring_buffer* rb)
{
    if (rb == NULL || rb->buffer == NULL)
        return false;

    int8_t data = *rb->data_start;
    rb->data_start++;
    if (rb->data_start == rb->buffer_end)
        rb->data_start = rb->buffer;
    rb->count--;

    return data;
}
```

It works as intended when I use it one at the time but the program crashes if I use it inside a loop with debuger pointing to "int8_t data = *rb->data_start;"

Edit:

This is the case I'm working on. The while loop doesn't cause any problem, it's for. Without it code works file, even if I manually replecate the loop by repeating the line n times. Unfortunetly I can't answer any question regarding the buffer, I'm a noob in C, I found this online and don't fully understand it, This is the full structere:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16468/circular-ringbuffer/20517

```
while(true){


    if(RB_pop(&test) == 255){

        if(RB_pop(&test) == 255){

            if(RB_pop(&test) == 254){



                char_count = RB_pop(&test);

                printf("Char count: ");
                printf("%d",char_count);
                printf("\n");

                printf("Text: ");

                int i;
                for(i = 0; i < char_count; i ++)
                    RB_pop(&test);

                checksum = RB_pop(&test);


                break;

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Edit 2:
I started working on other parts of program and experienced the same behavior, also noticed this messege from debugger:
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] recreating the problem, and edit your question to add it?

Comment: How do you distinguish from error (`return false;`) and zero (`return data;`)?

Comment: `int64_t count;` really large buffer

Comment: it is not ring buffer. Lets start from it. you should return data starting from the end not the start. You need FIFO but you implement LIFO